# jqgrid export not exporting right data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

when I export jqgrid to excel, I am not getting expected result. I am getting right data for two columns and for the rest columns it says undefined, also I am getting two extra columns at the end (please see the attached pic). I am using same export function for other jqgrid and I am getting right output there. I don't understand why I am getting this kind of result for this jqgird. I already spent more than 2 days on this but can't output right result. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```js
    $("#dataTable").jqGrid({
        url: '/test/getAllData.html',
        datatype: "json",
        colNames: ['id', 'Material name', 'Unit',  'Supplier', 'Date', 'Amount'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'id', index: 'id',width: 300 },
            { name: 'MaterialName', index: 'MaterialName', width: 300 },,
            { name: 'unit', index: 'unit', width: 300 },
            { name: 'supplier', index: 'supplier', width: 300 },
            { name: 'date', index: 'date', width: 300 },
            { name: 'amount', index: 'amount', width: 300 }
        ],
        rowNum: 100, 
        rowList: [25, 50, 75, 100],
        pager: '#dataTablePager',
        viewrecords: true,
        ignoreCase: true,
        loadonce: false,
        viewrecords: true,
        jsoonReader: {
     repeatitems:false;
    },
      loadComplete : function () {
     exportToExcel("dataTable"); //export function
    }
       
    });
```

```html
<div id="dataTable"/>
</div id="dataTablePager"/>
```

[image]

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used? Maybe you may need to look at your exprtToExcel function. Also we do not know if the export is done at server or with local JavaScript function. Too small information to solve the problem

Comment: @Tony Tomov the version is 4.6.0 and export done using java script. The export function is working perfect for other jqgrid

Answer (score 0):

There was some issues on export js function , export js function was setting colmodels manually with different names so I was getting undefined. I have fixed this issue